# JasperReports Server Installation fails while executing initdb.exe of postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jasperserver

*JasperReports Server 5.6.0*

I am able to successfully install *JasperReports Server* in unattended mode, when login to a specific machine as local Administrator. But I want to do the installation from a remote machine and am passing the same parameters as earlier(invoking the setup using CPAU for run as admin), but it fails while executing initdb.exe with the data folder creation.

I am getting the following error message as stated below.

```
"Executing initdb.exe -U postgres -E UTF8 -D C:/JASPER~1/JASPER~1.6/POSTGR~1/data
Script exit code: unknown signal
Script output:
Script stderr: child killed: unknown signal"
```

After googling and looking for a possible solution, I tried the following.

1) Created the data folder via cmd and provided full control permissions using cacls
2) Created the parent folder 'JasperServer' and provided inheritance permissions of OI, CI, Full Control.

But the issue appears to be the same. Though I am able to install *JR Server* with the same account by rdp in to the specific machine.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score -1):

pls try this:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/bundled-installer-fails-error-running-initdbexe

Reason: You are using domain admin account.
Solution:
change to local admin user and restart install procedure,then it works:-)
By, Kosta